# Adding form fields with null values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jquery function that goes through form integer values as entered and updates total in real time. It works fine except that when one of the values is null onload it doesnt work and gives error.

```
 function updateTotal(formObj) {
            var total = 0;
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt1.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt2.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt3.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt4.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt5.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt6.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt7.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.amt8.value, 10)
            formObj.sum.value = total
        }
```

Error i get is

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById('amt6').focus();
```

Please let me know how can i either ignore null values or place some check. Thanks

Comment: can you give a bit more code as at first glance it looks like the error lies else-where. However I will post a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = parseInt(formObj.amt1.value, 10);

if(test !== null){
   total += test;
}
```

There are MUCH better ways to do this but with info given.